# Proof of the Peaucellier–Lipkin linkage

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, proof-writing, circles

Please refer to the following linkage I have constructed in Geogebra. The segments $OB=OB=a$ and $BP=PC=CP'=P'B=b$ have fixed length at all times while $P$ can be moved along the red circle. All other points, especially $B$, $C$ and $P'$ are dynamically constructed and can't be moved manually. $M_{BC}$ is the midpoint of $B$ and $C$ while the line $f$ is the line through $O$ and $P'$ (and therefore $P$ as well).

---

[image: Peaucellier linkage]

---

Here is a short animated gif with my construction: http://g.recordit.co/oAnNgSuVvR.gif

---

**Construction protocol**

1. Let $O=(0, 0)$ and $M=(x,0)$ with arbitrary $x$. In my case $x=3$ is suitable.
2. Draw circle $c$ through $O$ with center $M$ (which is the red circle without name in my picture).
3. Pick an arbitrary point $P$ on $c$.
4. Pick suitable $a$ and $b$ which are implemented as sliders in my case. $a=7$ and $b=3$ with regards to my $M$ are reasonable.
5. Draw circle $d$ with center $O$ and radius $a$.
6. Draw circle $e$ with center $P$ and radius $b$.
7. Intersect the circles $d$ and $e$ and name the two points $B$ and $C$.
8. Draw the segments $OB$ and $OC$ as well as $BP$ and $CP$.
9. Draw a circle $f$ with center $B$ and radius $b$.
10. Draw a circle $g$ with center $C$ and radius $b$.
11. The intersection of $f$ and $g$ yields our already picked $P$ and $P'$ as well.
12. Draw the segments $BP'$ and $CP'$.
13. Move $P$ along the circle then the trace of $P'$ is a line.

---

**Claim.** The rotary motion of $P$ along the red circle implies that the trace of $P'$ is a straight line and vice-versa.

---

*Proof.* From the pythagorean theorem we can deduce

$$\begin{align*}(OM_{BC})^2 + (BM_{BC})^2 &= (OB)^2\\
(PM_{BC})^2 + (BM_{BC})^2 &= (PB)^2\end{align*}$$

Through trial and error I noticed that

$$\begin{align*}
OP\cdot OP' &= (OM_{BC} - PM_{BC})\cdot (OM_{BC} + PM_{BC}) \\
&= (OM_{BC})^2 - (PM_{BC})^2 \\
&= (OB)^2 - (BM_{BC})^2 - ((PB)^2 - (BM_{BC})^2) \\
&= (OB)^2 - (PB)^2\\
&= a^2 - b^2 \text{ is constant}.
\end{align*}$$

---

Unfortunately I don't know how to continue from here to show my claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the other intersection of the red circle with line $OM$, and $H$ the projection of $P'$ onto the same line.

If $P$ belongs to the red circle, then triangles $ONP$ and $OP'H$ are similar (they share an angle and both have a right angle), thus:
$$
HO:OP=OP':ON,
\quad\hbox{that is:}\quad
HO={OP\cdot OP'\over ON}={a^2-b^2\over 2r},
$$
where $r$ is the radius of the red circle, and I used your result $OP\cdot OP'=a^2-b^2$.

The length of $HO$ does not then depend on the position of $P$: that means that $P'$ lies on a line $t$, perpendicular to $OM$ and whose distance from $O$ is $OH=(a^2-b^2)/(2r)$, QED.

[image]

If, on the other hand, $P'$ belongs to line $t$ described above, then we have $OP\cdot OP'=HO\cdot ON$. Hence triangles $ONP$ and $OP'H$ are similar (they share an angle, comprised between proportional sides). It follows that $\angle OPN=\angle OHP'=90°$, and $P$ thus belongs to the circle of diameter $ON$, QED.

Comment: In your second part you mention the wrong angle, I guess you meant $OHP'$ instead of $ONP'$ being perpendicular?

Comment: Right, thanks. Corrected now.

Comment: Slightly offtopic since this does not refer to your proof. Have you considered the circle through $B$, $P$ and $P'$ or the circle through $C$, $P$ and $P'$? If I am not mistaken those should describe the inversion of the red circle along the green circle. Unfortunately I am not actually able to derive something that really shows this other that just by construction.

Comment: You can solve the exercise also by using inversion: line $HP'$ is the inversion of the red circle with respect to a circle of center $O$ and radius $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ (which is not the green circle). That follows easily from the properties of inversion and from $OP\cdot OP'=a^2-b^2$ and you can also check that with GeoGebra.