How to make Peaucellier–Lipkin linkage work?
First: Don't crucify me for not "doing math", or asking a dumb question. School was a long time ago, and lose what you don't use. My current math knowledge ends with "rule of proportion" (Correct term? I'm not a native English speaker).
Anyway: I recently came across a video speaking about 4-bar linkages, which linked this site: https://dynref.engr.illinois.edu/aml.html, which had this lovely image I had to try to recreate: Peaucellier-Lipkin linkage: However, I failed to make it work in onshape. Apparently, one or more bar ratios are wrong.
How do I calculate those? All I can find about that topic is so far over my head in terms of math, it might be as well Swahili written in Chinese characters.
This is where I am right now:  8-Bar-Link_OnshapeCAD
AB = BC = Arbitrary chosen 50mm
CD = CE = EF = DF = Arbitrary chosen 60mm
AD = AE = … Whatever mm. I just connected the points in my sketch.

Everything moves as it should until I connect bar AD to D, then it is over constrained for … Having the CD too short? … Too long? Wrong starting angle between CD and CE? (Hence AD/AE wrong length)
The example image  does look like it has 90° angles all around in that square.
P.S.: Would have been more comprehensive with inline images, but alas, I'm not allowed.


There's an underlying math question here, so this is a relevant place to post it. However, I wonder if Engineering.SE might be more practical; they even have a linkage tag.

Even if you had the lengths wrong it should still move, although F might not go in a straight line. Are you sure you are not imposing some hidden constraint to the movement, e.g. that D and E lie in a vertical plane? BTW, the wiki page is pretty good.

@JaapScherphuis Yeah. Wikipedia was my first stop. And then my native Wikipedia. And after understanding nothing, I came here. About constraints: No. Every arm is just connected to two rotational joints that can spin freely. Only B is limited to +-45° from where it is now.

@Blue Oh, thanks! I'll try there as well. But I thought it wasn't working because I got the math wrong. And I saw a post (I didn't understand) about a Peaucellier–Lipkin linkage proof here.

I made the linkage with GeoGebra, using your lengths, and it works. Here it is: https://geogebra.org/m/dag96wqe

@Intelligentipauca Oh! Thank you, thank you, thank you so much. … So it is CAD that is stupid … Or I'm too dumb to use it. (more likely honestly)

@Intelligenti Pauca (once more) please transform your comment into an answer...

@JeanMarie I don't think that's so relevant. And after all I had already given an answer on the same subject: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2354791/255730

"Too dumb to make Peaucellier–Lipkin linkage work ?" isn't a correct title. I have changed it into a more neutral version.
